# Three.js children to ignore scaling of parent object

Tags: three.js, scale

I am trying to model a galaxy that displays some stars. The planets are children of the star mesh. 
When you zoom, the star mesh gets bigger but I want at a certain zoom level, that the star remains the same size and only the planets increase in reference to the zoom scale.

This code is working just fine, but I am wondering if this is the best way and maybe there is another, better way to achieve this:

```
  var scale = instance.controls.scale;
  obj.scale.set(obj.scale.x*scale,obj.scale.y*scale,obj.scale.z*scale);
  for (var c = 0; c < obj.children.length; c++) {
      var child = obj.children[c];
      child.scale.set(child.scale.x/scale,child.scale.y/scale,child.scale.z/scale);
  }
```

The scale variable comes from the camera control that informs me how much zoom is applied. Zoom in will result in scale > 1 and scale out will result in scale < 1
In order to keep my star the same size if I zoom, I have to multiply it by the scale factor but because my planets are children of the star, I need to negate the scaling by doing the opposite.

Answer (score 4):

Add an extra container between the parent object and the children, like so:

```
var container = new THREE.Group();
obj.add( container );
containter.add( child );
```

Then,

```
obj.scale.multiplyScalar( scale );
container.scale.divideScalar( scale );
```

three.js r.71